# Unity. Input.MousePosition is returning coordinates that are way too large for the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The highest Y position that is shown in my camera is 5 and -5.
For the X its 10.
I'm making a tower defense game and I want the tower to follow my mouseposition after I buy it until I click on a place in the track to build/ place it. I got so confused because I couldn't see my tower at all but now I realized that my mouse coordinates are HUGE. It's up to the hundreds on each axis. My screen obviously can't fit that. I tried even dividing the mouseposition in a vector 2 by 45 and making an offset so it can fit well. Unfortunately I have to change the values depending on the screen size so that can't work. I don't know if it matters but here's my script? This script get's called after the tower gets instantiated from the store. The store button is in the canvas if that helps? Maybe the canvas is why everything is off? How do I fix it?

```
public class FrogBotPrefab : MonoBehaviour
{
    public frogbotshopscript shop;
    public canbuildManager buildingscript;
    public Vector2 mouseposition;
    public float xoffset;
    public float yoffset;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        xoffset = 9.55f;
        yoffset = 5.19f;
        shop = FindObjectOfType<frogbotshopscript>();
        buildingscript = FindObjectOfType<canbuildManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        mouseposition = Input.mousePosition/45;
        mouseposition.x -= xoffset;
        mouseposition.y -= yoffset;
        if (shop.followingmouse)
        {
         transform.position = mouseposition;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Screen space is different from world space

In Unity, `Input.MousePosition` is measured in terms of pixels on your screen. Let's say you have a 1080p monitor - 1920 x 1080 - which is pretty common these days, that means `Input.MousePosition` will be in the following range when your game is fullscreen:

- x: 0 to 1919
- y: 0 to 1079

The actual *world units* - the units as seen in your scene - don't matter at all and can be basically anything.

Another thing of note is that your gameworld is 3D and the physical screen is 2D. Assuming your camera is looking into open space in your world, a single pixel on the screen is represented by an infinite line in the 3D world. This line is called a ray, and you can turn a 2D screen position into a ray via [Camera.ScreenPointToRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html), and then find what 3D objects that line intersects with via a [Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).

Answer (score 0):

**In Unity there is a difference between the world position and the screen position!**

That means that just because you are looking at point AB at the world it does not have to be this point on screen because the Screen is meassured in Pixels.

There obv is a way to calculate a point on the screen based on your camera into the world. You best have a look at [Unity ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) for this.